# Azure Spring Cloud and JHipster

Tags: azure, jhipster, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry, azure-spring-cloud

Does anyone know if the built in config server with azure spring cloud should act the same as the JHipster registry? Currently having problems getting services to connect properly and identify each other. I've read the limited documentation from both JHipster and Microsoft, as it's new just wondered if anyone has had any luck with it?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? I am also trying to deploy JHipster application and I am getting 502 bad gateway when I try to hit API end points.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing official documentation from JHipster.

> The JHipster Registry has three main purposes:
>
> > It is a an Eureka server, that serves as a discovery server for
> >     applications. This is how JHipster handles routing, load balancing and
> >     scalability for all applications. It is a Spring Cloud Config server,
> >     that provide runtime configuration to all applications. It is an
> >     administration server, with dashboards to monitor and manage
> >     applications.

At the moment Azure Spring Cloud only support Eureka.
If there is no service discovery in your application. Azure Spring Cloud will enable Eureka as a default Service Discovery.

In my case, I was using consul and it was not working so I removed it and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running JHipster microservices, both should work the same - I've never experienced any difference myself, and I'm the original author of the JHipster Registry and I'm working at Microsoft as part of the Azure engineering team, working directly and daily with the Azure Spring Cloud team. I didn't code anything specific, it's just working out of the box because they are based on the same components.

The JHipster Registry is both a discovery server (Eureka) and a Spring Cloud Config server, which are packaged in the same application. We also add a nice UI, some security (with Spring Security), but the core features are the same.

In Azure Spring Cloud, we provide also a Eureka server and a Spring Cloud Config server - they are also slightly modified and enhanced (those are the enterprise versions coming from VMWare), but in the end those are the same Eureka and Spring Cloud Config servers.

In fact, for the next releases of JHipster, we are focusing on the [JHipster Control Center](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-control-center), which would abstract the JHipster Registry UI, so you could use it directly with Azure Spring Cloud.